# Alpha Relase of APK experiencing a very unusual launcher icon issue

Tags: android, google-play

I have a released production app which is all in place and works. Today I decided to release an Alpha version of the APK to a few users that are members of a Google Group.

The Play store DID show the "Update" button after a while for one of my accounts, and I successfully downloaded the alpha APK. But here's the weird bit.. There was no launcher icon for the updated app!!

So I uninstalled the APK, then re-installed from the Play Marketplace, now clicking on the "Install" button. The launcher icon appeared.

But I tried the exact same process again with another account, and again after an "Update" to the Alpha APK the launcher icon disappeared.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

(The device I was using to update/install was a Nexus 7 with 4.2.2 but I can't imagine that would have made a difference)

Comment: doesnt the N7 take it's launcher icon from the tvdpi folder, if you have some weird resource in there?

Comment: Make sure you updated all the dpi buckets, I've had this issue when I forgot to update one bucket or the other. Secondly some devices may cache the icon so try clearing the data and cache and restarting the device.

Comment: Thanks. But I know that the N7 is an xhdpi device, and it does have a launcher in the xhdpi folder. Are you saying that even still I need to have an icon in each other bucket?